# Probability of drawing without replacement at least one identical pair from two urns with n balls of n colors

Tags: probability

Given two urns with an identical set of $n$ balls of $n$ different colors, where $n$ is even. After drawing without replacement $n/2$ pairs from the first urn and also drawing without replacement $n/2$ pairs from the second urn, what is the probability that at least one identical pair has been drawn? The order within a pair should not matter, so (A,B) is considered identical to (B,A).

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps a similar problem is easier to solve: you may consider that each urn has $k$ identical balls. In this case, what is the probability of drawing one identical pair?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here... and I agree with @Ertxiem's suggestions about better describing what the difficulty is. Anyway, it's a bit difficult to understand the question: how many draws are done from the second urn? I would assume one, but the observation *again without replacement* makes me wonder whether it's a different number (e.g. $n/2$ like from the first urn, or anything in between).

Comment: Are these pairs *ordered* or *unordered?*

Comment: Thanks for the input, I rephrased the question.

Comment: Because of the many different possible patterns of $(A,A)$ and $(A,B)$ pairs obtained in the first urn's drawing, obtaining an exact formula would be annoying.  Asymptotically as $n$ grows large, though, the number of matches rapidly approaches a Poisson$(5/4)$ distribution.  This implies the probability of no match will be well approximated by $\exp(-5/4)\approx 28.65\%.$  This is fairly accurate even for $n\ge 10.$